# How do I return a filename as an ANT property?

Tags: file, ant, build, properties

I have a property file that is name app_id-*.app (where * = any application name that can be created) that I need to pass as an arg to an ANT exec call.

I was wondering if there is a way to return the full filename of the filename based on the wildcard as a property that I can then pass to another target.

Comment: Could you clarify the question some more? Do you need to read a directory, and then input the file name, or is it a build dependent file name that you can enter in a properties file or on the command line, etc?

Comment: Each application is created in a directory and consists of 4 files, each named differently. I need to return one of the filenames to pass to the exec call, which is one of the four files, and always starts with app_id_*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up creating a fileset and passing that to a property which worked great:

```
<path id="app-id-file"> 
    <fileset dir="@{path}"> 
        <include name="app_id_*.app"/> 
     </fileset>
</path>
<property name="application.id.file" refid="app-id-file"/>
<echo message="Application ID filename is ${application.id.file}" />
```